# Custom Authentication on Azure Mobile Services doesn't authorize

Tags: azure-mobile-services

After implementing the solution as described here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/

I can not get the authorization to work once I turned on

```
config.SetIsHosted(true);
```

It always returns 401 Unauthorized. My custom API controllers or any anonymous method works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 4.0.0 and it could either be a bug or a versioning issues as described here:

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/568067

Also due to another bug in the latest version as described here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/issues/325

We can't use Web API 2.2, so we need to downgrade to WebAPI 2.1.

In the end the solution is to get just the right package version numbers.

I could never get the latest version of WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend to work either so I had to downgrade that to the previous version.

Here is my package.config that shows all the packages and the version numbers that I finally got everything working on.

```
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RazorEngine" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="3.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend" version="1.0.342" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity" version="1.0.342" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables" version="1.0.342" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" version="2.3.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

**Update**

Even after upgrading all packages from the baseline that worked I could never get a successful upgrade, however I recreated the project from scratch and added everything back in and it now does successfully work at version 1.0.439. So I can say from this version that it is now working.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't update your backend nuget packages. We have specific versions in the hosting environment that will cause conflicts when you deploy. In the future, we'll improve this by hardcoding maximum version numbers for dependencies.